# Can't change macOS Time Zone in System Preferences

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac-appstore, monterey

The timezone of my Mac Monterey 12.5 is set to New York which is totally different from my current time and location. The strange thing about it is that I can't change my time zone. Also, the TouchID is deactivated so I have to keep entering the password. For example, I have to use the password for installing applications instead of TouchID.

Once I fixed these problems by reinstalling the operating system and it fixed for a while but again has these issues. The strange thing is that I don't see any error message from the operating system.

Does anyone know where the problem is and how I can fix it? If the problem is serious, does the App Store support it for free?

[image: Screenshot of the Date & Time preferences pane]

Comment: It could be that the default for the time zone is New York. As your screenshot shows, Location Services need to be on in order for the OS to determine your location and set the date/time accordingly.

Comment: Besides having LS turned on as @agarza already commented -additionally iCloud Private Relay can effect this - I move periodically between different countries in Europe, and the update can take some hours before the system "sees" my new location. I can usually force this by turning location services off and then on again.

Comment: Turn on location services and see if the ability to uncheck "Set time zone automatically" becomes available.  You can turn off the location services afterward.

Comment: FWIW, you can run `sudo systemsetup -settimezone 'America/Chicago'` (change that zone as needed) to set it from the command line.  Worked for me even with the zone not being editable in System Settings.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely a problem with user prefs, AppleID settings, Location Services, etc-- for which reinstalling the OS will do nothing.

I agree that turning off and on Location Services is your first option, and you need to fix whatever it is that causes TouchID not to work. You could try signing out and back into your AppleID.

It's certainly worth taking it to an Apple Store -- yes, it doesn't cost anything (unless it's a hardware issue, which seems unlikely here).

Answer (score 1):

Apple online support is free, so I would for sure get a case opened there. Second thing is to check if MDM profiles are managing this Mac (look for profiles in system preferences, if it’s not here, you have no MDM or profile).

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/allow-apps-to-detect-the-location-of-your-mac-mh35873/mac
- https://support.apple.com/choose-country-region

Lastly, might you be in a region where location is not provided?

This [particular issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/443241/5472) seems to have [cropped up](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/16443/5472) in the [past](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/204874/5472) as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's support site:

> The option to turn Set Automatically on or off may not be available with for all network providers or in all countries and regions. If the device has a Screen Time passcode or a corporate profile with device restrictions installed, then the option to turn Set Automatically on or off will be dimmed or greyed out.

Not sure if any of these situations apply to you.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a link for the quoted material. This could be of benefit to others that may come across this question/answer in the future.

Answer (score -1):

#### To change your timezone manually

Uncheck the box near the top that says "Set timezone automatically using current location."

#### If you would like it to be set automatically

You will need to turn on Location Services as mentioned. That setting is under Security & Privacy in System Preferences.

You should create a separate question for the TouchID issue.

Comment: as you can see in the picture the user is unable to check or uncheck the option. it is locked.

Comment: @FatemehKarimi Good catch, it should only look like that before the user unlocks. Looks like a bug. Turning location service on and then closing and reopening the window would still be my first advice.